# Angular JS Force iframe to reload

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm making an application, and I have different videos in the same page, I don't wanna to run different videos in the same time, So I want when the user play another videos I should reload the other iframes (So the videos stop automatically) ?

Is there anyway to manipulate with iframe from controller and if you can provide a simple example or any thing that can solve this problem wich I have been working on for more that two days.

Controller :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.video1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/wsXWjj88vKo';
    $scope.video2 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/FVXajf9ALPM';
}
```

Html :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<iframe  ng-src="{{video1}}" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <iframe  ng-src="{{video2}}" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/14550/)

Or any way to force reloading a button for example :

```
 $scope.reload = function() {
   $scope.video1 = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/wsXWjj88vKo';
    };
```

Comment: i had used a custom directive ng-refresh, which would watch a variable and refresh the page if that variable changed

Comment: Can you please give me an example of this directive or if you can apply it on my example that would be great

Answer (score 0):

example refresh directive

```
csapp.directive('csReloadOn', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {

var getTemplate = function () {
    return '<div ng-if="doRefreshPageOnModeChange"><div ng-transclude=""></div></div>';
};

var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = true;

    scope.$watch(attrs.csReloadOn, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal === oldVal) return;
        scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = false;
        $timeout(function () { scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = true; }, 100);
    });
};

return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude: true,
    template: getTemplate,
    link: linkFunction
};
}]);
```

how to use it

```
     <div cs-reload-on="someVar">
             ----- contents to reload ----
     </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand good your example ! is there any possibility to give me a JSfiddle or Codepen example ! I would appreciate it

Comment: any variable on whose change you want to reload the contents